# Why use "as tall as" rather than "such a tall person that"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> She told herself that she could actually become as tall as she wanted.

Why use " as tall as" rather than " such a tall person that"?

Comment: Could you please explain why you think "as tall as" is wrong?  For example, *"I want to get as rich as I can"* is perfectly normal English.  Have you read something that says it's not?

Comment: Erm... because *such a tall person that* syntactically / logically requires that it be followed by some clause defining a condition or action that would only be possible for a person at least as tall as she was (or hoped to become). For example, *She told herself that she could actually become such a tall person that **she would be able to see over the high wall***.

Answer (score -1):

*Such* means "[of the kind mentioned or implied](http://www.yourdictionary.com/such)."

If you followup a *such X* with a later *that*, then you're "undoing" the "implied" meaning of *such*, which is contradictory and confusing.

> She told herself that she could actually become such a tall person.  (Fine, we're referring to "a tall person" that was previously mentioned or implied)
>
> She told herself that she could actually become such a tall person that she wanted.  (Now sounds like there's a specific tall person the writer/speaker had in mind that the implication created by *such* didn't cover - doesn't work.)

Of course, if only she has an idea of how tall she wants, and we know she is less tall than that amount, *as tall as she wanted* expresses this perfectly without us having to know precisely how tall that is, or otherwise read her mind.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that your second version *(...such a tall person that she wanted)* is syntactically invalid *whatever* text precedes it.

Comment: What you say in your comment is the same mistake OP is making.  Qualifying *such X* after the fact is a misuse of *such*.

Comment: "She told herself that she could actually become such a tall person that she could never be overlooked again."  Qualifying *such x* after the fact seems quite ordinary.  The problem with OP's proposition is that "that she wanted" isn't a sensible postcedent for "such a tall person".

Comment: @LawrenceC - I think you are confusing several definitions of *such*.  It can mean *of the type* and it can mean *to a high degree*.   *Such a tall person that...* means *A person whose height is so extreme that....* -- they can reach a second story window, for example.